# Terraform with EKS

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

i'm trying to learn how to use the EKS and terraform services.
i'm trying to work with this manual (from the official documentation):

[Provision an EKS Cluster (AWS)](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/eks?in=terraform/kubernetes)

[Manage Kubernetes Resources via Terraform](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/kubernetes-provider?in=terraform/kubernetes)

but after waiting for 10 minutes for creating the service, i'm getting time exceeded.
since it's an official documentation manual, what have i done wrong?

***updating my post as requested:***
my terraform code was as mentioned in the manuals (officiatl documentation), the errors i've got are:

```
    data.terraform_remote_state.eks: Reading...
data.terraform_remote_state.eks: Read complete after 0s
data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster: Reading...
data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster: Read complete after 1s [id=education-eks-bD9EYEuJ]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the
following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # kubernetes_deployment.nginx will be created
  + resource "kubernetes_deployment" "nginx" {
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + wait_for_rollout = true

      + metadata {
          + generation       = (known after apply)
          + labels           = {
              + "App" = "ScalableNginxExample"
            }
          + name             = "scalable-nginx-example"
          + namespace        = "default"
          + resource_version = (known after apply)
          + uid              = (known after apply)
        }

      + spec {
          + min_ready_seconds         = 0
          + paused                    = false
          + progress_deadline_seconds = 600
          + replicas                  = "2"
          + revision_history_limit    = 10

          + selector {
              + match_labels = {
                  + "App" = "ScalableNginxExample"
                }
            }

          + strategy {
              + type = (known after apply)

              + rolling_update {
                  + max_surge       = (known after apply)
                  + max_unavailable = (known after apply)
                }
            }

          + template {
              + metadata {
                  + generation       = (known after apply)
                  + labels           = {
                      + "App" = "ScalableNginxExample"
                    }
                  + name             = (known after apply)
                  + resource_version = (known after apply)
                  + uid              = (known after apply)
                }

              + spec {
                  + automount_service_account_token  = true
                  + dns_policy                       = "ClusterFirst"
                  + enable_service_links             = true
                  + host_ipc                         = false
                  + host_network                     = false
                  + host_pid                         = false
                  + hostname                         = (known after apply)
                  + node_name                        = (known after apply)
                  + restart_policy                   = "Always"
                  + service_account_name             = (known after apply)
                  + share_process_namespace          = false
                  + termination_grace_period_seconds = 30

                  + container {
                      + image                      = "nginx:1.7.8"
                      + image_pull_policy          = (known after apply)
                      + name                       = "example"
                      + stdin                      = false
                      + stdin_once                 = false
                      + termination_message_path   = "/dev/termination-log"
                      + termination_message_policy = (known after apply)
                      + tty                        = false

                      + port {
                          + container_port = 80
                          + protocol       = "TCP"
                        }

                      + resources {
                          + limits   = {
                              + "cpu"    = "0.5"
                              + "memory" = "512Mi"
                            }
                          + requests = {
                              + "cpu"    = "250m"
                              + "memory" = "50Mi"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                  + image_pull_secrets {
                      + name = (known after apply)
                    }

                  + readiness_gate {
                      + condition_type = (known after apply)
                    }

                  + volume {
                      + name = (known after apply)

                      + aws_elastic_block_store {
                          + fs_type   = (known after apply)
                          + partition = (known after apply)
                          + read_only = (known after apply)
                          + volume_id = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + azure_disk {
                          + caching_mode  = (known after apply)
                          + data_disk_uri = (known after apply)
                          + disk_name     = (known after apply)
                          + fs_type       = (known after apply)
                          + kind          = (known after apply)
                          + read_only     = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + azure_file {
                          + read_only        = (known after apply)
                          + secret_name      = (known after apply)
                          + secret_namespace = (known after apply)
                          + share_name       = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + ceph_fs {
                          + monitors    = (known after apply)
                          + path        = (known after apply)
                          + read_only   = (known after apply)
                          + secret_file = (known after apply)
                          + user        = (known after apply)

                          + secret_ref {
                              + name      = (known after apply)
                              + namespace = (known after apply)
                            }
                        }

                      + cinder {
                          + fs_type   = (known after apply)
                          + read_only = (known after apply)
                          + volume_id = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + config_map {
                          + default_mode = (known after apply)
                          + name         = (known after apply)
                          + optional     = (known after apply)

                          + items {
                              + key  = (known after apply)
                              + mode = (known after apply)
                              + path = (known after apply)
                            }
                        }

                      + csi {
                          + driver            = (known after apply)
                          + fs_type           = (known after apply)
                          + read_only         = (known after apply)
                          + volume_attributes = (known after apply)

                          + node_publish_secret_ref {
                              + name = (known after apply)
                            }
                        }

                      + downward_api {
                          + default_mode = (known after apply)

                          + items {
                              + mode = (known after apply)
                              + path = (known after apply)

                              + field_ref {
                                  + api_version = (known after apply)
                                  + field_path  = (known after apply)
                                }

                              + resource_field_ref {
                                  + container_name = (known after apply)
                                  + divisor        = (known after apply)
                                  + resource       = (known after apply)
                                }
                            }
                        }

                      + empty_dir {
                          + medium     = (known after apply)
                          + size_limit = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + fc {
                          + fs_type      = (known after apply)
                          + lun          = (known after apply)
                          + read_only    = (known after apply)
                          + target_ww_ns = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + flex_volume {
                          + driver    = (known after apply)
                          + fs_type   = (known after apply)
                          + options   = (known after apply)
                          + read_only = (known after apply)

                          + secret_ref {
                              + name      = (known after apply)
                              + namespace = (known after apply)
                            }
                        }

                      + flocker {
                          + dataset_name = (known after apply)
                          + dataset_uuid = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + gce_persistent_disk {
                          + fs_type   = (known after apply)
                          + partition = (known after apply)
                          + pd_name   = (known after apply)
                          + read_only = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + git_repo {
                          + directory  = (known after apply)
                          + repository = (known after apply)
                          + revision   = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + glusterfs {
                          + endpoints_name = (known after apply)
                          + path           = (known after apply)
                          + read_only      = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + host_path {
                          + path = (known after apply)
                          + type = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + iscsi {
                          + fs_type         = (known after apply)
                          + iqn             = (known after apply)
                          + iscsi_interface = (known after apply)
                          + lun             = (known after apply)
                          + read_only       = (known after apply)
                          + target_portal   = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + local {
                          + path = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + nfs {
                          + path      = (known after apply)
                          + read_only = (known after apply)
                          + server    = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + persistent_volume_claim {
                          + claim_name = (known after apply)
                          + read_only  = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + photon_persistent_disk {
                          + fs_type = (known after apply)
                          + pd_id   = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + projected {
                          + default_mode = (known after apply)

                          + sources {
                              + config_map {
                                  + name     = (known after apply)
                                  + optional = (known after apply)

                                  + items {
                                      + key  = (known after apply)
                                      + mode = (known after apply)
                                      + path = (known after apply)
                                    }
                                }

                              + downward_api {
                                  + items {
                                      + mode = (known after apply)
                                      + path = (known after apply)

                                      + field_ref {
                                          + api_version = (known after apply)
                                          + field_path  = (known after apply)
                                        }

                                      + resource_field_ref {
                                          + container_name = (known after apply)
                                          + divisor        = (known after apply)
                                          + resource       = (known after apply)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                              + secret {
                                  + name     = (known after apply)
                                  + optional = (known after apply)

                                  + items {
                                      + key  = (known after apply)
                                      + mode = (known after apply)
                                      + path = (known after apply)
                                    }
                                }

                              + service_account_token {
                                  + audience           = (known after apply)
                                  + expiration_seconds = (known after apply)
                                  + path               = (known after apply)
                                }
                            }
                        }

                      + quobyte {
                          + group     = (known after apply)
                          + read_only = (known after apply)
                          + registry  = (known after apply)
                          + user      = (known after apply)
                          + volume    = (known after apply)
                        }

                      + rbd {
                          + ceph_monitors = (known after apply)
                          + fs_type       = (known after apply)
                          + keyring       = (known after apply)
                          + rados_user    = (known after apply)
                          + rbd_image     = (known after apply)
                          + rbd_pool      = (known after apply)
                          + read_only     = (known after apply)

                          + secret_ref {
                              + name      = (known after apply)
                              + namespace = (known after apply)
                            }
                        }

                      + secret {
                          + default_mode = (known after apply)
                          + optional     = (known after apply)
                          + secret_name  = (known after apply)

                          + items {
                              + key  = (known after apply)
                              + mode = (known after apply)
                              + path = (known after apply)
                            }
                        }

                      + vsphere_volume {
                          + fs_type     = (known after apply)
                          + volume_path = (known after apply)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

  # kubernetes_service.nginx will be created
  + resource "kubernetes_service" "nginx" {
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + status                 = (known after apply)
      + wait_for_load_balancer = true

      + metadata {
          + generation       = (known after apply)
          + name             = "nginx-example"
          + namespace        = "default"
          + resource_version = (known after apply)
          + uid              = (known after apply)
        }

      + spec {
          + allocate_load_balancer_node_ports = true
          + cluster_ip                        = (known after apply)
          + cluster_ips                       = (known after apply)
          + external_traffic_policy           = (known after apply)
          + health_check_node_port            = (known after apply)
          + internal_traffic_policy           = (known after apply)
          + ip_families                       = (known after apply)
          + ip_family_policy                  = (known after apply)
          + publish_not_ready_addresses       = false
          + selector                          = {
              + "App" = "ScalableNginxExample"
            }
          + session_affinity                  = "None"
          + type                              = "LoadBalancer"

          + port {
              + node_port   = (known after apply)
              + port        = 80
              + protocol    = "TCP"
              + target_port = "80"
            }

          + session_affinity_config {
              + client_ip {
                  + timeout_seconds = (known after apply)
                }
            }
        }
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + lb_ip = (known after apply)

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

kubernetes_deployment.nginx: Creating...
kubernetes_deployment.nginx: Creation complete after 6s [id=default/scalable-nginx-example]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Creating...
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [1m20s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [1m30s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [1m40s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [1m50s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [2m0s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [2m10s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [2m20s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [2m30s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [2m40s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [2m50s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [3m0s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [3m10s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [3m20s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [3m30s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [3m40s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [3m50s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [4m0s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [4m10s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [4m20s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [4m30s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [4m40s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [4m50s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [5m0s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [5m10s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [5m20s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [5m30s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [5m40s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [5m50s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [6m0s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [6m10s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [6m20s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [6m30s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [6m40s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [6m50s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [7m0s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [7m10s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [7m20s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [7m30s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [7m40s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [7m50s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [8m0s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [8m10s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [8m20s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [8m30s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [8m40s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [8m50s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [9m0s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [9m10s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [9m20s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [9m30s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [9m40s elapsed]
kubernetes_service.nginx: Still creating... [9m50s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: context deadline exceeded
│ 
│   with kubernetes_service.nginx,
│   on kubernetes.tf line 97, in resource "kubernetes_service" "nginx":
│   97: resource "kubernetes_service" "nginx" {
│ 
╵
```

Comment: Do you have any terraform code?

Comment: i'm using the codes from the manual, just to understand the basic concepts. after making the default codes work - i'll adjust it as i see fits.

Comment: So you are using the first link to create the cluster and nodes? And that does not work?

Comment: i'm assuming the first one is just to create the cluster, and the second one is for deploying a simple nginx image. the first one works just fine, the second one manage to get into errors and timeouts.

Comment: share an error screenshots if anything there that would be helpful.

Comment: i've updated my question with the logs

Comment: I'd try with the updated resources versions: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/service_v1 and https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/deployment_v1.